# What is the right way to post an after-action report?

Tags: discussion

I posted [How can I choose a free calculus textbook?](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/4482/how-can-i-choose-a-free-calculus-textbook) in 2014, then our department adopted a free calculus textbook. We made various decisions at that time.

Three years out, we know more or less what the outcome was, and I'd like to share it with the site. How should I do so? I could imagine:

- As a series of comments to my original answer
- As another answer to my original question
- Asking a new question and answering it ("How is Guichard's Community Calculus?")

Or something else. The reason I'm not just immediately posting another answer is that a lot of the issues with what we ended up choosing aren't about free calculus textbooks, but are more about the specific textbook and its specific issues.

Thanks for your thoughts.

Comment: I think best is to edit your question with a section called "3 year later followup".  People want to see things in the same place.  More efficient than a new question (that's not even really a question).  Don't underestimate how many people do Google searches and use old Q&A.

Answer (score 7):

Both answering the original and posting a new self-answered question seems fine to me. Given the specific circumstances you describe the latter seems better. Just try to phrase the question in such a way that at least in principle somebody else might answer, too. To mention the other question for context could also make sense.

Regarding  the use of comments, a problem is that they have low visibility. Something related that is sometimes done is to edit the question to add such information at the end of the body of the post, as an 'update' or 'resolution.' You could do this in this case, too; mentioning the new question.